# Task Parallel Library - building a tree

Tags: c#, tree, task-parallel-library

I'm having trouble with this. I've got "WorkItem" which has a method DoWork. WorkItem can have dependencies which MUST complete before it does, otherwise it throws an exception.

Here's a diagram, where each item (A, B, C, etc.) is a WorkItem. The first items off the rank should thus be A, B, E, as they have no dependencies.

[image: Diagram]

So I throw "G" to DoWorkForTask, but my exception throws itself, proving that, say, A and B haven't completed before C runs. The whole tiny project is [zipped up here.](http://www.dukecg.net/ThreadedBuilder.zip)

```
    private void DoWorkForTask(WorkItem item)
    {
        // NOTE: item relies on Dependents to complete before it proceeds
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            foreach (var child in item.Dependents)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(child.DoWork, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

                if (child.Dependents.Count > 0)
                    DoWorkForTask(child);
            }

            item.DoWork();
        }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
    }
```

Note that I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149873/task-parallel-library-for-directory-traversal) and it does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to encapsulate the structure of the "workflow" into the WorkItem class. But if you don't really need to, something antecedent-based like this would work:

```
var A = Task.Factory.StartNew(
  () => Console.WriteLine("A"));
var B = Task.Factory.StartNew(
  () => Console.WriteLine("B"));
var E = Task.Factory.StartNew(
  () => Console.WriteLine("E"));
var C = Task.Factory.StartNew(
  () => { Task.WaitAll(A, B); Console.WriteLine("C"); });
var D = Task.Factory.StartNew(
  () => { Task.WaitAll(C, E); Console.WriteLine("D"); });
Task.Factory.StartNew(
  () => { Task.WaitAll(E, D); Console.WriteLine("F"); })
    .ContinueWith(a => Console.WriteLine("G"));
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks suspicious to me:

```
Parallel.ForEach(item.Dependents, child => DoWork());
```

You're ignoring the `child` - you're just calling `DoWork` as many times as you have children.

Did you mean:

```
Parallel.ForEach(item.Dependents, child => child.DoWork());
```

?

Comment: Sorry, I added back in my original DoWorkForTask().

Comment: @George: Okay, it's hard to get to grips with all the little bits you've got here. Could you show us a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @George: You still haven't posted a complete program. I want something I can compile and run. You've only posted a *method*.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to provide a mechanism for the child tasks to complete e.g. Task.WaitAll(