# Most efficient way to find all exe files on disk using C#?

Tags: c#

**What is the most efficient way to find all exe files on disk using C#?**

It will be done in background thread in program so disk usage should be as small as possible.

Comment: What have you done so far? You can enumerate all the directories of the machine and use the overload of Directory.GetFiles that takes a file pattern (e.g. ".exe"). If it is running, you might find qurying the Windows Search database to be much faster as it will have preindexed much of this info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231256(v=vs.85).aspx. There's no guarantee the Windows Search database is up to date, so simply enumerating all of the directories and and using Directory.GetFiles might be the most accurate, at least.

Comment: So far, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458

Comment: Note that the GetFiles/EnumerateFiles method is already covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c - you can simply use a filter for exe files when searching a directory.

Comment: similar question answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724148/is-there-a-faster-way-to-scan-through-a-directory-recursively-in-net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link you provided is the most efficient way in C# (with .Net 4.0): 
[Directory.EnumerateFiles Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458)

Prior versions of .Net had to use a slower method that caused memory issues on large drives, @hatchet showed a great example: [Is there a faster way to scan through a directory recursively in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724148/is-there-a-faster-way-to-scan-through-a-directory-recursively-in-net)

I wouldn't suggest using the TPL as Jon Skeet mentions here:
[Task Parallel Library for directory traversal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149873/task-parallel-library-for-directory-traversal#comment14095131_4149873)

If you see the first comment in this [MSDN link: Iterate File Directories with the Parallel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477033.aspx) I dont even think Microsoft had success with this TPL method either.

The other suggestion I have is using LogParser and you can use it with C#! Its a free  Microsoft product but I'm not sure about re-dist permissions, I had to include it in my package separately last time I used it. It full on flys, faster than a speeding train!

As per @spender comment I found a [Log Parser example](http://forums.iis.net/t/1183252.aspx) that finds files dated 180 days and older, you could try it out and adapt it if its useful:

```
SELECT
    ContentPath, [Days (Old)], FileName, [Creation Date Time]
    USING creationtime AS [Creation Date Time],
    TO_DATE([Creation Date Time]) AS Cdate,
    SUB(TO_LOCALTIME(SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP()), Cdate) AS Days,
    DIV(TO_INT(Days),86400) As [Days (Old)],
    EXTRACT_PATH(TO_LOWERCASE(path)) AS ContentPath,
    TO_LOWERCASE(name) AS FileName
FROM %source% 
WHERE
  (attributes NOT LIKE 'D%')
AND
  ([Days (Old)] >= TO_INT('%day%'))
ORDER BY [Creation Date Time] DESC
```

%source% could be something like c:\*.exe as shown in the argument c:\temp\*.*. Save the above as cc.sql, run it with the following syntax:

```
 C:\Temp\Tools\Logparser>LogParser.exe file:cc.sql?source="c:\temp\*.*"+day="180"  -i:FS -preserveLastAccTime -rtp:-1
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for the upvotes guys! I made this [Event Analyser](http://EventAnalyser.AppointmentsBook.com) app in 2005 (before .net 2.0 was released) and since the Log Parser suggestion was so popular I thought I'd share the way you can use LogParser in .Net

> The good folks over at http://visuallogparser.codeplex.com/ have
>   provided us with the source code.

Open the [VisualLogParser](http://visuallogparser.codeplex.com/) solution in VS2010, ignore the prompt about debugging, after the solution loads, F5, set the combo-box to FS (FileSystem), paste in this query and press go.

```
SELECT
    ContentPath, [Days (Old)], FileName, [Creation Date Time]
    USING creationtime AS [Creation Date Time],
    TO_DATE([Creation Date Time]) AS Cdate,
    SUB(TO_LOCALTIME(SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP()), Cdate) AS Days,
    DIV(TO_INT(Days),86400) As [Days (Old)],
    EXTRACT_PATH(TO_LOWERCASE(path)) AS ContentPath,
    TO_LOWERCASE(name) AS FileName
FROM 'c:\*.exe' 
WHERE
  (attributes NOT LIKE 'D%')
AND
  ([Days (Old)] >= TO_INT('180'))
ORDER BY [Creation Date Time] DESC
```

*At the same time you may wish run any other .Net application that searches directories and compare the results!!!*

Comment: It's not obvious how LogParser is relevant to the task of searching for .exe files.