# Read XML from EventLog in Windows Event Viewer on Windows XP with C#

Tags: c#, windows-xp, event-log

How do I get the XML from a specific `EventLogEntry` using `C#` on Windows XP? I already know the `EventLog` type (Security) and the event entry id.

`EventLogWatcher` and other classes are only available in Windows Vista and newer.

Comment: [LogParser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logparser) is a utility built by an X Microsoft Employee Gabriele Giuseppini that reads a tonne of log file formats. I've used it with [Event Logs](http://eventanalyser.appointmentsbook.com) before.

Comment: Is there a C# interface to it?

Comment: Yes there is. The good folks over at http://visuallogparser.codeplex.com/ have it baked ready. Here is a quick [demo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965280/most-efficient-way-to-find-all-exe-files-on-disk-using-c/10965388#10965388)

Comment: @jjxtra Since I came here for the same reason (though not for Windows XP as the target), and did not like the suggested solutions for third-party tools and libraries, I provided the solution that worked for me... see below.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [LogParser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logparser). Its a utility built by an x Microsoft Employee Gabriele Giuseppini that reads a tonne of log file formats - [FAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965280/most-efficient-way-to-find-all-exe-files-on-disk-using-c/10965388#10965388)!

I've successfully used it with [Event Logs](http://eventanalyser.appointmentsbook.com/) before.

There is a C# interface from the good folks over at http://visuallogparser.codeplex.com

Comment: I don't need to create anything, I just want to read an existing event out of an event log

Answer (score 0):

For Windows XP, you can use the `EventLogReader` and `EventLogQuery` classes to query `EventLogRecords` from the event log quite efficiently. This API is available since .NET Framework 3.5 (so it should work perfectly fine on Windows XP).

First, you need the name of the event log to query (either its file system path or name), and second an XPath expression that acts as the record selector. A few examples are given at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/consuming-events

Basically, it works as follows:

```cs
static string RetrieveApplicationEventDetailsXmlById(string eventId)
{
    const string logName = "Application";
    string queryExpression = string.Format("*[System/EventId=\"{0}\"]", eventId);
    var eventLogQuery = new EventLogQuery(logName, PathType.LogName, queryExpression);

    using (var reader = new EventLogReader(eventLogQuery)) 
    {
        EventRecord record;
        if ((record = reader.Next()) != null)
        {
            return record.ToXml();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Given that a valid XPath expression has been specified, a call to the reader´s `Next` method returns the next available `LogEventRecord` object that allows retrieving the event´s details in XML format via the `ToXml` method.